# How to turn a tuple/list into a filename?

Tags: python, filenames

I have a list that takes some parameters from an image. And I need to save this image with this parameters on its name. I am calling it a list, but maybe it can be another thing, I am having trouble on identifying what type it is. On error box it's calling it "tuple".

It takes the filename of image, and all parameters from  my code, then, turns each into string.

```
list = str(filename), str(cci[i]), str(gamma[j]), str(alfa[m]), str(beta[n]), "{:.4f}".format(uci), "{:.4f}".format(uiq)
```

When I print the list, this is what appears:

```
('GOPR0395.JPG', '0.8', '0.6', '0.4', '0.4', '5.8829', '3.5720')
```

And that's what I need in the new image I am going to save. I need this whole thing, separated. And i only know how to save it making its filename a string, like this:

```
cv2.imwrite(f'{DIR_results}{str(filename)}', image)
```

I wish the filename for "image" was

```
GOPR0395_08_06_04_04_53829_35720.JPG
```

Any tips? Thank you

Comment: for the record, a tuple is another collection type that is very similar to a list. It has one very notable difference that, unlike a list, it is immutable  - meaning that once declared or created, it cannot be changed. You use the tuple in much the same way as the list - you ca slice it, iterate over it and use the join method to combine its elements (see my answer below)

Comment: @GalodoLeste Got it. Thank you so much for clearing that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
x = ('GOPR0395.JPG', '0.8', '0.6', '0.4', '0.4', '5.8829', '3.5720')
my_str = '_'.join(x) .replace('.', '').replace('JPG', "") + '.jpg'
```

Comment: Good spot. Edited above

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Further, I figured out that I was missing replacing the dots

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing something like this:
first you replace all your commas with a +Then you add  + '_'
between every string you add. You can use .replace('a','b') to get rid of the dots and the ".JPG". At the end your code should look something like this:

```
filename = (str('GOPR0395.JPG').replace(".JPG","") + "_"+ str('0.8')+"_"+  str('0.6')+ "_"+ str('0.4')+"_"+  str('0.4')+ "_"+ str('5.8829')+ "_"+ str('3.5720')).replace('.','') + ".JPG"
```

be aware that I replaced all you variables with the input they represent because I dont know what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

Using the tuple example above you could split the first element on the `.` to separate the filename from the extension before joining (keeping the `.extn` outside the `replace` function).  This would allow for images other than just JPG's.

```
x = ('GOPR0395.JPG', '0.8', '0.6', '0.4', '0.4', '5.8829', '3.5720')
filename =  '_'.join(((splits:=x[0].split("."))[0], *(x[1:]))).replace('.','') + f'.{splits[1]}'
print(filename) # GOPR0395_08_06_04_04_58829_35720.JPG
```